# Spring MVC, and JDBC datasources

Tags: spring-mvc, error-handling, datasource

In all the examples you see for configuring the `servlet-context.xml` in a Spring MVC web-app any datasource required is configured as a bean in this file, probably using a connection pool defined in the container. For example in my `servlet-context.xml` for my `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` I initialize my datasource thusly:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
jndi-name="java:comp/env/jdbc/ora1"
expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"
resource-ref="true" />
```

If, in the case where the database is down for some reason, the web-app errors at the initialization stage and throws a yard-and-a-half of Java stack trace into the browser, something like this:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet appServlet threw exception at      
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1214) at  
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:809) at 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:615)
```

... and so on.

**I have 2 questions:**

1. Is it possible to trap this error and display something more friendly to the user? I personally doubt it is as the servlet cannot get beyond the `init()` stage.
2. Is is valid **NOT** to initialize the datasource in the servlet context and do it dynamically from a @Controller as the connection is required? As with more conventional methods e.g:

   ```
   public static DataSource getJndiDataSource() throws NamingException {
       Context initialContext = new InitialContext();
       DataSource ds = (DataSource)initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/ora1");
       return ds;
   }
   ```

Thanks for any responses!

Comment: What's causing the exception thrown in your servlet `init()` method?

Comment: The fact that the DB is offline and the `dataSource` object cannot be created. I don't have control over the DB but need to account for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

1. Users should never see exceptions, period.  You ought to have a friendly error page configured that tells the user the site is down and to come back later.  The stack trace should only appear in your logs.  You need the detail to figure out what the problem is.
2. No, this is something that should be handled by the app server before your app is brought up.  The connection pool should be initialized successfully before your app is up.  Don't try to do it in the Controller.

Perhaps your connection pool configuration is incorrect.  I'd recommend scrubbing that thoroughly to make sure it's right.  You have several parameters available to you, like checking connections before they're released from the pool, etc.  Look into those.

UPDATE:

It's always possible for a DBA to bring down a database.  I'd suggest that you initiate a dialog with them so they give you a heads up and an outage window.  Make it possible for your app to display a "down for maintenance" page, a la Stack Overflow.

Comment: (1) I know this, but I am asking **how** to trap an error on the initialization of the servlet, to subsequently display a friendly error page! (2) I have no control over the database and if the DBA sees fit to take it offline I want my web-app to fail gracefully.

Comment: (1) http://developingdeveloper.wordpress.com/2008/02/20/handling-exceptions-in-spring-mvc-part-1/ (2) Stil invalid to do things in controller.  The first answer will correct it as gracefully as you can.

Comment: So you're saying there isn't a way to trap an error at the init() stage of a Spring MVC servlet, so as not to dump a stack trace to the browser? This is the question I'm asking. If it isn't possible I don't have a problem with that - I would just like to know so I can get on with something else! I tried the suggestions in the link you supplied but I think the exceptions trapped here are at a later stage than `init()`